# Modifying the oscola citation style

Tags: biblatex

I would like to make several modifications to the `oscola` citation style, but have little experience with modifying `biblatex` styles. I'm hoping these are not difficult modifications and that someone can assist.

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[style=oscola, ibidstyle=uc, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\bibliography{example.bib}

\begin{document}
Example\footcite{housen2002}, another\footcite[3]{housen2002}, one more\footcite{crestonmoly2014}, again\footcite[45]{housen2002}, and again\footcite[45]{housen2002}.
\end{document}
```

The `example.bib` contains:

```
@jurisdiction{crestonmoly2014,
title = {Creston Moly Corp. v. Sattva Capital Corp.},
shorttitle = {Creston Moly},
number = {2014 SCC 53},
volume = {373},
reporter = {D.L.R.},
series = {4th},
pages = {393},
date = {2014},
pagination = {paragraph},
keywords = {ca},
}

@jurisdiction{housen2002,
title = {Housen v. Nikolaisen},
shorttitle = {Housen},
number = {2002 SCC 33},
volume = {[2002] 2},
reporter = {S.C.R.},
pages = {235},
date = {2002},
pagination = {paragraph},
keywords = {ca},
}
```

This produces:

[image: Text]
[image: Footnotes]

My required modifications, by footnote number, are:

1. Footnote: A comma following the name of the case (*Housen v Nikolaisen*, 2002 SCC 33...)
2. Footnote: Ibid set in italics, with no comma following ibid, and "at" preceding the pinpoint (*Ibid* at para 3.)
3. Footnote: Pinpoint following the first cited reporter, with "at" preceding the pinpoint (*Creston Moly Corp v Sattva Capital Corp*, 2014 SCC 53 at para 100, 373 DLR...)
4. Footnote: Instead of (n 1), this: *Housen*, *supra* note 1 at para 45.
5. Footnote: Since the pinpoint is the same as in footnote 4, it should be omitted (*Ibid*.)

Comment: You need to at least provide the caselaw bibliography.

Comment: Sorry! Caselaw bibliography sample added to the original post.

Comment: Also: are you hoping to get *McGill Guide* compliant output? (I hope to look into this during the summer. No time now. Shouldn't even *be* on this site!!!) Hopefully someone can offer some fixes for these issues, but I think *McGill*-compliance calls for complete overhaul, or possibly something rebuilt from the ground up....

Comment: Yes @jon _McGill Guide_ compliance is what I'm after. I agree that a McGill-specific project would be best and would make it easiest to incorporate formatting changes in new versions of the guide. That said, **oscola** already incorporates a number of the functions that are required by McGill (e.g. ibid tracking, supra ability). Most of the changes required to make **oscola** more McGill-like seem to me (while noting that I am a biblatex n00b) to be mostly cosmetic instead of functional. If you start a project during the summer, please let me know, as I will be happy to contribute.

Comment: It is not impossible to make these changes to `oscola`, but it is  very tedious due to the structure of the package. To make sure that everything is cited as intended the packages has to go quite some length and introduce a lot of logic and we have to change things in lots of places. To achieve your first request alone there are at least six places to change each of them with 10 - 20 lines of code resulting in 107 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Not an OSCOLA answer, but could be useful.

[image: ibid mcgill]

If it helps, there's a `\lawcite-in-McGill-mode`  .tex file as a standalone MWEB, too big to post here, at gitbranch: https://github.com/texcicada/lawcite/blob/mcgill/lawcite_mcgill_minidemo.tex (and [PDF](https://github.com/texcicada/lawcite/blob/mcgill/lawcite_mcgill_minidemo.pdf)).

Background

`\lawcite` uses the methodology of options, collected into sets, to define various styles: MLR, AGLC, McGill etc, with the ability to change individual options, or even entire styles, mid-document as required. It is built on top of a standard extended Biblatex style `ext-authortitle-ibid`, where ibid-tracking is built-in (not all legal styles use ibid, though). `\lawcite` adds three additional bibentry types, `@case`, `@statute` and `@ljarticle`, adds fields to the datamodel to handle the required level of granularity of detail, and defines two main additional citation commands, `\lawcite` itself for cases and statutes (and regulations) and `\ljcite` for law journal articles and law review essays.

A case:

[image: case citation]

A statute:

[image: statute citation]

From a law journal:

[image: law journal]

Plus a handful of useful lower-level citation commands. The commands etc that come with `ext-authortitle-ibid` intentionally remain as-is.

McGill bibliographic structure is driven by standard Biblatex filtering and refcontext methods.

`\lawcite`'s design intention is cross-jurisdictional capability combined with ease of maintenance/switching.

Disclaimer: the McGill settings are definitely going to be incomplete in one way or another because they are based on what was able to be gleaned from a handful of university library web pages and from the international section in the AGLC. McGill itself is still only hardcopy, it seems.

`\lawcite` is still a work-in-progress in the overall sense, but the three citation commands are fairly stabilized. There are also two additional, experimental, processing methodologies: one, a "front-end" method, where the sequence of elements and their formatting is user-defined (in effect a type of legal citation markup tagging in the bibentry itself), combining with expl3 regex-replace to map to Biblatex commands; and the other method, which uses the stylename itself as part of the format/command name so the code (instead of the user) handles the plurality of element/formatting sets.

(Note: Once the documentation has been plumped up and testing done, the mcgill git sub-branch will be merged back into the main branch.)